# I am having adapter problem. Can anyone know the solution

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Can anybody help me to sort out this problem? I looked similar question posted by other learner, still I am not able to solve my problem. When the app runs, the activity displays only white screen.

My catlog shows below error:
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout.

Here is my code:

Order Status Activity:

```
package com.example.android_foodbot;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.android_foodbot.AccountActivity.User;
import com.example.android_foodbot.Model.Request;
import com.example.android_foodbot.ViewHolder.OrderViewHolder;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class OrderStatusActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder> adapter;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference requests;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_status);
    enter code here

        //Firebase
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        requests = database.getReference("Requests");

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.listOrders);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);



        //Getting current user details
        String uid;
        FirebaseAuth auth;
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        uid = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
//                if (user==null){
//                    Toast.makeText(OrderStatusActivity.this, "NUll user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                }
//                else{
//                    Toast.makeText(OrderStatusActivity.this, "user is "+user.getPhone(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                }

                loadOrders(user.getPhone());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException();

            }
        });



    }


    private void loadOrders(String phone){
//        Toast.makeText(this, "phone is "+phone, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder>(
                Request.class,
                R.layout.order_layout,
                OrderViewHolder.class,
                requests.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(phone)) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(OrderViewHolder viewHolder, Request model, int position) {
                viewHolder.txtOrderId.setText(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                viewHolder.txtOrderStatus.setText(convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus()));
                viewHolder.txtOrderPhone.setText(model.getPhone());



            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }


    private String convertCodeToStatus(String status){
        switch (status) {
            case "0":
                return "Placed";
            case "1":
                return "Processing";
            default:
                return "Served";
        }

    }


}
```

Order View Holder:

```
package com.example.android_foodbot.ViewHolder;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.android_foodbot.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.example.android_foodbot.R;

public class OrderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView txtOrderId, txtOrderStatus, txtOrderPhone;

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public OrderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txtOrderId = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_id);
        txtOrderStatus = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_status);
        txtOrderPhone = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_phone);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), false);

    }
}
```

Order Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OrderStatusActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listOrders"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"

        >


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I checked my adapter then I found that getItemCount() method is returning 0 value. Can anyone know how to solve this??

```
private void loadOrders(String phone){

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder>(
            Request.class,
            R.layout.order_layout,
            OrderViewHolder.class,
            requests.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(phone)) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(OrderViewHolder viewHolder, Request model, int position) {
            viewHolder.txtOrderId.setText(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
            viewHolder.txtOrderStatus.setText(convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus()));
            viewHolder.txtOrderPhone.setText(model.getPhone()); //                Toast.makeText(OrderStatusActivity.this, "Show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




        }


    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    if (recyclerView != null){
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Recycler View is not null ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    if (recyclerView == null){ //            Log.v("TAG", "RECYCLERVIEW NULL");
        Toast.makeText(this, "RECYCLERVIEW NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (layoutManager == null){ //            Log.v("TAG", "LAYOUTMANAGER NULL");
        Toast.makeText(this, "LAYOUTMANAGER NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (adapter == null) { //            Log.v("TAG", "mFIREADAPTER NULL");
        Toast.makeText(this, "mFIREADAPTER NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else if (adapter != null) { //            Log.v("TAG", "mFIREADAPTER NULL");
        Toast.makeText(this, "FIREADAPTER IS NOT NULL" +adapter.getItemCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


}
```

Comment: Since you're assigning the adapter inside a listener, the adapter is only initiated and assigned to the recyclerView wrt Firebase. Can you verify that there's data in Firebase?

Comment: You are setting the adapter in a background thread. Please check the duplicate to see how you can solve this.

Comment: Yes, there is data in the firebase database. And when I used toast tag inside loadOrders() method, it displays the user details but I couldn't display the same details inside populateViewHolder() method. Any more suggestion??

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

in the `onCreate` to initialize `reyclerView` at first not when the query finishes and when the query finishes just update the `adapter` variable with new data.

Happy Coding

Comment: I have attached that line in loadOrders(String phone) method. It didn't work also i tried adding that line at the beginning of onCreate() method. Nothing works out. Any further suggestion??